# How can you find the expected winnings from this game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, random-variables

A player pays £4 to play a game in which they select an ordered pair (a<sub>G</sub>, <sub>bG</sub>),
such that each digit is selected from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} with replacement. A random
number generator then selects one of the twenty five options each with equal
probability. If the player selects at least one digit correctly (in the correct
position), they are awarded £W back, such that
W = (a<sub>G</sub> + b<sub>G</sub>), if the player wins.
0, if the player loses.
The profit or loss X is therefore
X = −4 + W .

Calculate the expected winnings of each of the following strategies:

(S1) Selecting (a<sub>G</sub>, <sub>bG</sub>) = (4, 4) every time.

(S2) Selecting (a<sub>G</sub>, <sub>bG</sub>) at random each with probability 1/25

Attempted Answer for S1:

| W | 8 |
| --- | --- |
| X | 4 |
| E(X) | 2/25 |

(2/25 as you can have (4,4) in either order)

Therefore, expected winnings = 8/25

S2: I have counted all the possible combinations of (a<sub>G</sub>, <sub>bG</sub>) (e.g (0,0) (0,0) (1,0) (0,1).. etc) and this comes to more than 25 so I think the answer involves combinatorics but I am unsure how to solve it.

Comment: The users here will ask you to describe what you have tried to solve this problem. Could you please edit the question text and describe your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let's have a look at $S1$ first:**

If you guess $(4,4)$ then you will win if and only if the computer has a $4$ in their answer. The probability that the computed does *not* have a $4$ anywhere is $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{16}{25}$. As they must (independently) select either a $0,1,2,3$ or $5$ for the first digit *and* the second digit. (Each of these events occurs with probability $\frac{4}{5})$

Hence the probability you get at least $1$ digit correct (i.e win the game ) is $1-\frac{16}{25} = \frac{9}{25}$. 
And so your expected **income** from this game is $W \cdot \frac{9}{25} + 0 \cdot\frac{16}{25} = 8\cdot\frac{9}{25} = \frac{72}{25} \approx 2.9 $.

Your expected value of playing the game is simply $\frac{72}{25} - 4 = -\frac{18}{25}$

**Let's look at $S2$**

$S2$ is slightly more tricky but we can take advantage of linearity. We should point out three things first:

1. Expectation is linear. That is we can simply add up income from each digit.
2. By symmetry the first and second digit selection will contribute identically to your expectation.
3. The probability that you win is always $\frac{9}{25}$ regardless of your guess.

If your first digit was a $2$ then you would receive $£2$ with probability $\frac{9}{25}$ and some more money from your second digits guess. Thats the say the expected value of having guessed $2$ in the first digit is $2 \cdot\frac{9}{25} = \frac{18}{25}$.

Your expected winnings of guessing $(A_g , B_g)$ is then simply $A_g \cdot \frac{9}{25} + B_g \cdot \frac{9}{25} = \frac{9}{25}(A_g + B_g)$

When guessing each of the $25$ options we see the expected value of $A_g  = \frac{0+4}{2} = 2$ as we guess uniformly. Similarly the same result for $B_g$. Hence the expected value of your income when randomly guessing is just $\frac{9}{25}(2+2) = \frac{36}{25}$

Then expected value of the game is simply $\frac{36}{25} - 4  = -\frac{64}{25} = -2.56$

Bad game. Dont play it.

You can be a bit more formal with the law of total expectation.

Comment: Thank you so much!!